# static NSString generates compilation warnings

Tags: xcode, static, nsstring

In a simple `NSObject` subclass that conforms to `NSCoding` protocol, I declare some static `NSString` in my header file :

```
static NSString *MYCodingKey = @"myPropertyName";
...
```

I wonder why Xcode is generating so many warnings about the fact I declare but don't use it. I understand the warning since the subclass is imported in many files and I don't employ the key for something in each. But so, does it mean that my key is in some way 'redefined' each time I import the header ? Doesn't the `#import` statement prevent the header from being included multiple times ? I surely don't have warning saying I've declared it multiple times.

I'm just ignoring these warnings at the time, but I would be glad to read a bit more on that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the warning is because you have a variable declared but you're not using it. Essentially you're just wasting space in the programs data section with things you're never going to use. Some compilers will optimize it and actually remove it if the symbol is not used (not sure if gcc with objc flag does so).

Comment: The problem is that it generates one warning per key and per `#import`. Then the yellow list rapidly grows up. Since I archive the instance using them and use some of them for other things 'outside' the class I think they are at the right. But why the warning so ?

Comment: I've never really worked too much with Obj-C but did you make sure that you put directives to avoid importing the same thing multiple times? such as #ifndef MYHEADER_H ....etc

Comment: It might have something to do with the way objective c works since everything is dynamically typed and evaluated at runtime. So each file is compiled individually which is why you get so many warnings.